# Wordpress post-search URL redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am suffering wordpress redirect URL problem
I am going to redirect

http://mydomain.xxx/tiger  ->   http://mydomain.xxx/?s=tiger

I used the following code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(.*)?$ index.php?path=$1$2   [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The code is working for test.php , but not working for wordpress.
I think it is WordPress related problem
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: is your project folder name tiger ?

Comment: Tiger is not folder name , it is wordpress keyword